# Postgresql error statement is too large

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I developed a script on python and sqlalchemy to get and update the last activity of my active users.

But the users are increasing a lot, now i´m getting the following error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: Statement is too large. Statement Size: 16840277 bytes. Maximum Allowed: 16777216 bytes
```

I was thinking if I update the file *postgres.conf* it will work, so with the help of pgtune I updated the file, but it does not work, so I updated my kernel on */etc/syslog.conf*, with the following parameters

```
kern.sysv.shmmax=4194304
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=32
kern.sysv.shmseg=8
kern.sysv.shmall=1024
```

and again it does not work.

After that I divide my query into slices to reduce the size but I got the same error.

How can know what parameter I need to update, to increase the size of my statement?

Workflow

```
query = "SELECT id FROM {}.{} WHERE status=TRUE".format(schema, customer_table)
ids = ["{}".format(i)for i in pd.read_sql(query, insert_uri).id.tolist()]

read_query = """
SELECT id,
 MAX(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Mexico_City', last_activity)) lastactivity
FROM activity WHERE
DATE_TRUNC('d', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Mexico_City', last_activity)) =
DATE_TRUNC('d', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Mexico_City', CURRENT_DATE))-{} and
 id in ({})
GROUP BY id
""".format(day, ",".join(ids))

last_activity = pd.read_sql(read_query, read_engine, parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: Do you really need a statement 16840277 bytes long?

Comment: Indeed, I've thought this limit is like 167772 % larger than the maximum statement that we'd conceivably need in our application that does some really badass analytics. Where's the SQLAlchemy code?

Comment: Yes, this workflow reduced considerable the time of my process, it is not normal?
I have ~800k users, but some users are inactive, so first I have to determine what users are active, and after I compute only the users active with this workflow I can reduced the time.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I updated my workflow, I'm using pandas to read the database and return a DataFrame to transform other stuff.

Comment: You *must not* format your parameters into the query; you must use placeholders instead.

Comment: Thank you after apply your suggestion it works I need to read more about this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only fetching the IDs from the database and not filtering them by any other way, there is no need to fetch them at all, you can just insert the SQL statement as a subquery into the second:

```
SELECT id,
 MAX(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Mexico_City', last_activity)) lastactivity
FROM activity WHERE
 DATE_TRUNC('d', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Mexico_City', last_activity)) =
 DATE_TRUNC('d', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Mexico_City', CURRENT_DATE))-%s and
 id in (
    SELECT id FROM customerschema.customer WHERE status=TRUE
 )
GROUP BY id
```

Also, as Antti Haapala said, don't use string formatting for SQL parameters, because **it is insecure** and if any parameter contains appropriate quotes, postgres will interpret them as commands instead of data.

Comment: That's the way to do it. You have a database, so you should use its power.